# Tree menu with php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql, tree

I'm trying to build a tree menu. The problem is recursion. Queries are coming from another php  page with functions. However doing like that the program can't get out of while loop(like its the first time the query function called) and boom, infinite loop...

Here is code:

```
<?php

include ("connection.php");
include ("getQueries.php");

$brandId = 1;
$modelId = 1;
$brands = getBrands($brandId);
$models = getModels($brandId);
$motors = getMotors($brandId,$modelId);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($brands)){

?>
    <ul class="nav nav-list" style="padding-top: 10%">
        <li><label class="tree-toggler nav-header"><?php echo $row['marka']; ?></label>

<?php

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($models)){

?>
    <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
        <li><a href=''#'><?php echo $row2['model']; ?></a></li>

<?php

    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($motors)){

?>
            <ul class="nav nav-list tree" style="padding-left: 15%">
                <li><a href='#'><?php echo $row3['motor']; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
<?php
    }
    $modelId++;
?>
    </ul>

<?php
}
$brandId++;
?>
</li>
    </ul>
<?php
}
```

And the query page:

```
<?php

include ("connection.php");

function getBrands($brandId){

$brands = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM araba_marka WHERE id = '$brandId'");
return $brands;
}

function getModels($brandId){

$models = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM araba_model WHERE marka_id = '$brandId'");
return $models;
}

function getMotors($brandId,$modelId){

$motors = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM araba_motor WHERE marka_id = '$brandId' AND model_id = '$modelId' ORDER BY motor ASC");
return $motors;
}
```

**Edit:** Infinite loop problem has been solved. But now by getting queries just once(at the beginning, not like parameters), there is a new problem. If there are 2 or more elements in same category, while loop runs only once because there was just 1 element at the beginning.

Comment: it's infinitely looping because you're calling `while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc(getModels($brandId))){` instead you should call `while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($brands)){` and same with the other loops.

Comment: what do your tables look like? maybe your third inner loop is dependent upon the second loop which may be dependent upon the first loop.

Comment: you're incrementing the modelId but you're not using it maybe add `$motors = getMotors($brandId,$modelId);` just right before you call your 3rd inner loop.

Comment: Are you try to list all brands? if you are i think you should drop the `WHERE id = '$brandId'` in your getBrands query. that way it'll loop through all brands. Then before you call your second loop, you should call `$models = getModels($row['id']);` that way it'll return all models for each brand. and you might have to do something similar for the 3rd loop like calling `getMotors($row['id'],$row2['id]);` so that it'll grab all motors for that brand and model.